# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How do I solve the following problem when I run the code?

service = service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Sounds like you forgot a `from` with your `import`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the detailed code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are so many problems in your code:-

1. You import service module like this:

   `from selenium import webdriver`
   `import Service`
   `import ChromeDriverManager`

but actually you have to import like this
`from selenium import webdriver`
`from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service`
`from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager`

2. Update your modules to latest version
3. Dont use modules name as variables